# Mysql throwing error while executing a code

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

This is my sql code :

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN delc = ''',
      delc,
      ''' then ''y'' end),''n'') AS ',
      delc
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM inputr;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT tem, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM inputr 
                  GROUP BY tem');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

When I execute this in `mysql workbench 6.3`, I am getting `error code 1064`

What is the issue?
This is the error :

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'plan,COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN delc = 'sil' then 'y' end),'n') AS sil,COALE' at line 1    0.000 sec
```

Comment: Show the query that you are actually executing -- that is the value of `@sql`.  The error will probably be obvious.

Comment: this is the complete thing  I am executing

Comment: Note: You probably don't have to even use `COALESCE` in your first query; just make the `ELSE` value `n`.

Comment: can you help me witth the query

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to the structure of the final query.  My guess is that one or more values of `delc` has a single quote or a backslash.

The simplest solution is just to eliminate these by only accepting "normal" names

```
select . . .
from inputstr
where delc regexp '^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$'
```

These characters are allowed as identifiers and in strings, so the code should then work.